# Need help trying to parse file and create map in scala

Tags: scala

I am having a hard time wrapping my head around how to parse a csv file and post it to a webservice using scala.

The basic idea is I need to create post params from the csv file.  There for the header would be the parameters and the following rows would be the values ie.

example csv

```
firstname, lastname, age, weight, height
John, Doe, 30, 180, 72
Mary, Jane, 28, 120, 64
```

This would map to parameters
`firstname=John&lastname=Doe&age=30&weight=180&height=72` etc.

I have the following scala to parse the data but can't seem to figure out what to do next:

```
val lines = fromFile("runners/io/m2m/naf/ARDS.csv").getLines
      for ((line, cnt) <- lines.zipWithIndex) {
        if (cnt == 0) {
          for((header, i) <- CsvParser.parse(line).view.zipWithIndex){

          }
        }else {
          for((data, i) <- CsvParser.parse(line).view.zipWithIndex) {

          }
        }
      }
```

Comment: store headers in a map indexed by `i`, and then for each `data` item, lookup the map and output header=data. need more help?

Comment: Yeah I figure I can use immutable maps and such but it seems like there should be a functional approach to this problem.

Comment: oh, it wasn't specified in the question that you're looking for a 'functional approach'..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about this?

```
val lines = fromFile("runners/io/m2m/naf/ARDS.csv").getLines
val header = CsvParser.parse(lines.next)
val rowMapsIterator =
  for (line <- lines)
    yield (header zip CsvParser.parse(line)).toMap
```

Then the results look like:

```
scala> for((map, cnt) <- rowMapsIterator.zipWithIndex) println(cnt + ": " + map)
0: Map(firstname -> John, weight -> 180, lastname -> Doe, age -> 30, height -> 72)
1: Map(firstname -> Mary, weight -> 120, lastname -> Jane, age -> 28, height -> 64)
```

To get that &-separated format, you would instead do:

```
val rowStringIterator = rowMapsIterator.map(_.map { case (k, v) => k + "=" + v }.mkString("&"))
```

This gives you:

```
scala> for ((s, cnt) <- rowStringIterator.zipWithIndex) println(cnt + ": " + s)
0: weight=180&firstname=John&height=72&age=30&lastname=Doe
1: weight=120&firstname=Mary&height=64&age=28&lastname=Jane
```

Answer (score 0):

I used dhg's answer, but flattened the lists, since CsvParser was giving back a List[List[]].

Thus -

```
val header = CsvParser.parse(lines.next).flatten


val rowMapsIterator =
 |   for (line <- lines)
 |     yield (header zip CsvParser.parse(line).flatten).toMap
```

This gave me a map of header col to data column mapping

```
scala> rowMapsIterator.foreach(println)
Map(weight -> 180, firstname -> John, height -> 72, age -> 30, lastname -> Doe)
Map(weight -> 120, firstname -> Mary, height -> 64, age -> 28, lastname -> Jane)
```