# How to make map of csv formatted string with 2 columns in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a predefined CSV formatted string where it will always represents two rows with multiple columns. How can I load this as a map in Scala? 
Sample CSV formatted string:

```
"Name","Age","Country","State"

"A","26","xx","yy"
```

Expected Map with keys as `"Name"`,`"Age"`,`"Country"`,`"State"` and with corresponding values as `"A"`,`"26"`,`"xx"`,`"yy"`

Note each of the string is a free form text and can contain `,;"` or any character.

Edit : 
My csv data is not stored in external file. CSV formatted text is available to me in my json in string format. I'm looking at possible solutions other than saving this text to disk in csv file and loading it back again with **spark.read.csv** as this would be too expensive in my case where millions of records exists which would be endinup with creation of millions of csv files. Though we can think of deleting them at the end

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Need help trying to parse file and create map in scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8884722/need-help-trying-to-parse-file-and-create-map-in-scala)

Comment: So you already have this inside a dataframe? Can you edit the question to show how the dataframe looks in that case, and what you expect as output.